# Python Request: Dont wait for put to complete

Tags: python, python-requests

I am setting the timeout value to 1 second to a put request so that I don't wait for it to complete, however, does it cancel the request or it does continue in the background?

Comment: I believe the server continues processing the request, but you won't receive the eventual response.

Comment: @JohnGordon you are completely right. Please post this as a reply and will mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my observation, time-out does not cause the request to cancel. The operation (PUT, POST etc) continues to get processed in the server.